# Yield HTML attribute through slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, slim-lang, content-for

I'm trying to generate an html tag attribute in slim through content_for.

The output I would like to get is the something like :

```
body data-turbolinks="false"
```

What I've tried (that work) is the following :

#### from my view

```
- content_for(:body_attributes) do
  =false
```

#### and from my app template

```
body data-turbolinks=(yield(:body_attributes) if content_for?(:body_attributes))
```

But I don't find the right syntax if I want to pass on the attribute AND its value from my content_for.

I've tried many things with no chance like :

```
body*{(yield(:body_attributes) if content_for?(:body_attributes)}
```

or

```
body[(yield(:body_attributes) if content_for?(:body_attributes)]
```

with something like this in my view :

```
- content_for(:body_attributes) do
  = "#{'data-attribute=false'}"
```

Thanks for any idea !

---

Regarding comments :

```
# Template
body*{yield(:body_attributes) if content_for?(:body_attributes)}
# View
- content_for(:body_attributes) do
  ="data-turbolinks=>false"
```

OR

```
# Template
body*{yield(:body_attributes) if content_for?(:body_attributes)}
# View
- content_for(:body_attributes) do
  data-turbolinks=false
```

Produces :

```
syntax error, unexpected modifier_if, expecting => s(({yield(:body_attributes) if content_for?(:body_attributes
```

---

```
# Template
body(yield(:body_attributes) if content_for?(:body_attributes))
# View
- content_for(:body_attributes) do
  ="data-turbolinks=>false"
```

OR

```
# Template
body(yield(:body_attributes) if content_for?(:body_attributes))
# View
- content_for(:body_attributes) do
  data-turbolinks=false
```

Produces :

```
Slim::Parser::SyntaxError Expected attribute
```

Comment: can you show us what the output html is for each of these things you tried? Note: have you tried `="false"`  along with `data-turbolinks="(yield(:body_attributes)"`?

Comment: Hi Tarny, thx for your comment, I want to output the attribute AND the value from my content_for, if I wrote ="false" yes it will work if my html is something like body data-turbolinks=(yield(:body_attributes)). In cases I've tried something like = "#{'data-attribute=false'}" or = "data-attribute=>false' in my content_for, I get an "expected attribute" error from rails. My implied question is : is it possible to yield html attribute with slim ?

Comment: Sure - can you show us what the output html was for the things you tried? ie what does "tried many things with no chance" actually look like? ;) what did you actually observe? Then we can help you write what something that will actually work...

Comment: I added some tests I've done (rails error no html output)

Comment: a) I *think* that a named `yield` will just output nil if there isn't content... given it's complaining about the if... it might be worth trying without `if content_for?` (and also testing on a page that doesn't define it). b) did you try modifying your first option to match the `expecting` syntax given? (seems to have extra parentheses as well as the curly braces) c) if slim is expecting there to always be an attribute... can you use a ternary operator and put a dummy/replacement attribute if there is no content?

Comment: Why not just set the value to a variable? Like:  data-turbolinks="#{some_var}" and then just set some_var to false in content_for

Comment: Are you trying to create something that will work for any attribute or just for data-turbolinks? If the latter, something like what @bkunzi01 says should be enough